# Redirect with URL change

Tags: grails

I am using the following code to validate something and then redirect:

```
    def validateSomething(){
    if(.....){
       ...
        redirect(controller:'some', action:'index' )
        return
    }
   }
```

it redirects and renders the index action but does not change the URL in the address bar. The url remains "..../validateSomething". I am submitting a form with a value to this action.(I am using Grails 3.0.12).

Comment: @tim_yates But forward does not change the URL. I want the URL to change as per the action I am redirecting/forwarding to.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the URL in the address bar to change, you could use something like this:

> redirect(uri: "/some/index")